# Why, on entering a wrong type of value as input, the variable "b" is always assigned to 1?

Tags: c, output

In this simple code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
     int a, b;
     scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
     printf("\nThe value of a is : %d",a);
     printf("\nThe value of b is : %d",b);
}
```

When I enter a wrong type of value as input, the variable b is always getting assigned to 1.
I have tried to add another variable "c" and printed its value at the end of the code, but still the variable "b" is always assigned to 1.
Why?

[image: The output:-]

Comment: You are invoking an undefined behavior here. Why do you think it is even "assigned" anything? You don't know what was there before.

Comment: When `scanf` doesn't successfully convert two numbers, it won't change the value of `b`. So `b` is uninitialized, and can take any value. Try initializing `a` and `b`, e.g. `int a = 123, b = 456;`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you call `doubts.exe 1 2 3`, do you still get 1? You could be getting, by accident, the value that would be going in `argc` if you had defined `main` that way. But of course it could be something entirely different; *the behavior is undefined*.

Comment: I recall some lengthy debates about whether or not printing an indeterminate value is UB.

Comment: @trentcl No on calling doubts.exe 1 2 3 i get the value 2 inside "b".

Comment: @user3386109 I don't want to initialize the variables, I was just curious to know that whether there is some rule that is being followed.
Because when i add another variable say "c", it gets "0" as it's value if any wrong input is provided, but the variable "b" sticks to 1.

Comment: The rule is that you should not use variables that might have not been initialized to a value. In your case you can either initialize them or to check the return value of `scanf` to make sure it is successful.

Comment: @user3386109 AFIK you cannot guarantee that.

Comment: @klutt Are you saying `a` and `b` will become indeterminate even if were initialized?

Comment: It looks like the standard is specifying the flow of conversion/assignment step-by-step, and only successful conversions are assigned.

Comment: @klutt In the section on fscanf: Example 4 in paragraph 21: The value of d2 is not affected.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  The behaviour of `scanf()` with respect to the value of arguments corresponding to failed conversions is not explicitly specified, so in theory could be modified.  In practice however they would be weird - and would probably break some existing code unnecessarily. The standard may be more explicit than the user documentation (I have not looked), but the standard is primarily intended for library implementers.

Comment: @eugenesh. The standard committee says that passing an indeterminate value to a library function has undefined behaviour. One obvious reason is that any function can be inlined or a macro and it can evaluate the indeterminate value many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If value of a `scanf()` argument after `scanf()` returns is undefined if the conversion was unsuccessful, but the most likely behaviour is that it remains unchanged.  In this case `b` is uninitialised so could have any value regardless of the behaviour of `scanf()` .

Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a = -1, b = -1;
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    printf("\nThe value of a is : %d",a);
    printf("\nThe value of b is : %d",b);

    return 0 ;
}
```

I would expect in this case both `a` and `b` to have either the entered value or -1 if the conversion fails - even though that is not actually required.

`scanf()` returns the number of arguments converted and assigned.  Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    int convert = scanf("%d %d",&a,&b) ;
    if( convert > 0 )
    {
        printf("\nThe value of a is : %d",a);

        if( convert > 1 )
        {
            printf("\nThe value of b is : %d",b);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nThe value of b is undefined" );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nThe value of a is undefined" );
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

For your test input `54test hello` it outputs:

```
45test hello

The value of a is : 45
The value of b is undefined
```